# StringBuilder uses more memory when append is used

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, string-concatenation

```
{
    StringBuilder fileBuff = new StringBuilder();
    long before = getUsedMem();
    try {
    //Open InputStreamReader here
        while ((currLine = lnr.readLine()) != null) {
            fileBuff.append("\r\n" + currLine);
        }
     //Close streams
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("usedTotal: " + (getUsedMem() - before));
}

private long getUsedMem() {
    return Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
}
```

While running the code several times, I get **usedTotal** ~ **14279888**, but if I replace with `fileBuff.append("\r\n").append(currLine)` I get almost double the memory ~**33264440**.
Can somebody please explain the reason, as I know `String` concatenation also uses `StringBuilder`?

I:  fileBuff.append("\r\n" + currLine);

```
      62: aload         6
  64: invokevirtual #16                 // Method java/io/LineNumberReader.readLine:()Ljava/lang/String;
  67: dup           
  68: astore_2      
  69: ifnull        99
  72: aload_1       
  73: new           #2                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
  76: dup           
  77: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
  80: ldc           #17                 // String \r\n
  82: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  85: aload_2       
  86: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  89: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
  92: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  95: pop           
  96: goto          62
```

II fileBuff.append("\r\n").append(currLine)

```
      62: aload         6
  64: invokevirtual #16                 // Method java/io/LineNumberReader.readLine:()Ljava/lang/String;
  67: dup           
  68: astore_2      
  69: ifnull        86
  72: aload_1       
  73: ldc           #17                 // String \r\n
  75: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  78: aload_2       
  79: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  82: pop           
  83: goto          62
```

Clearly #II should use less memory, but it doesn't. The file I am reading is 50k long.

Comment: "*StringBuilder uses more memory when append is used*". Yes it does, so the array won't be expanded every time something is appended.

Comment: @johnchen902 I think this should be an answer, not a comment...

Comment: @Puce Not an answer when I didn't find a proof.

Comment: @johnchen902 looking at code, it is expanded each time:    `public AbstractStringBuilder append(String str) {
        if (str == null) str = "null";
        int len = str.length();
        ensureCapacityInternal(count + len);
        str.getChars(0, len, value, count);
        count += len;
        return this;
    }`

Comment: @CristiL Yes, I have seen the code (before I commented). But I doesn't consider those codes as a proof (unless JDK version and vendor are specified).

Answer (score 6):

When using `StringBuilder` you're reserving space to add strings to your buffer. This is a good example to use `StringBuilder` rather than string because you're using a while loop.

When you're using a `String`, every time you type something like this:

```
String s = s + someOtherString;
```

You're throwing away your existing `s` string and creating a new one to go instead of it which is `s + someOtherString`. This means that you're constantly needing new memory to make the concatenated string, throw the old one out, and put the reference of your variable to your new string.

With a `StringBuilder` you can append to your string without having to remove the existing part.

So yes, it uses more memory, but it's very efficient in some scenario's compared to using just a string.

In other words: `String` is an [immutable object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) and a `StringBuilder` isn't.

---

**In your code:**

```
fileBuff.append("\r\n" + currLine);
```

This is the same as `new String("\r\n" + currLine);` which is 1 String object

You're using 1 append.

**In your comment you say that if you use this:**

```
fileBuff.append("\r\n").append(currLine);
```

This is the same as `new String("\r\n");` and `new String(currLine);` which are 2 String objects

You get almost double the memory. That makes sense because you're doing 2x append, thus using double the memory.

Comment: Hi, I am already using StringBuilder , which is more efficient than StringBuffer. Also, I get higher memory usage while NOT using the String concatenation. If I use s = s + someOtherString I use only half of the memory.

Comment: Oh, I put `Stringbuffer` instead of `StringBuilder` I'm sorry! I changed it now

Comment: I agree with you that the theory says that, but in practice is seems its not the same:   fileBuff.append("\r\n" + currLine) will use less memory than fileBuff.append("\r\n").append(currLine)

Comment: +1 very well explained. @Cristil your memory is less in  case of string because you free memory after concat but in case of append every string resides in array.

Comment: @CristiL That's because you're using 1 append in `fileBuff.append("\r\n" + currLine)` and 2 appends in `fileBuff.append("\r\n").append(currLine)` 1 append = x memory and 2 appends is 2x memory. It makes sense that using 2 appends means using double the memory.

Comment: Not sure I understand: why would 2 appends use more memory, since its a buffer with a preallocated memory, and 1 append + a new String would use less. String concatenation still uses a StringBuilder in the backgroud, so each time it should create a new Object, while for append it uses the same instance. Quoting: "This means that you're constantly needing new memory to make the concatenated string", so append takes more memory than concatenation?

Comment: @CristiL It's because you're not throwing away your old variable like you would when you're concatenating a string using `String s = s + someOtherString`. You're keeping the same memory reference instead of making a new (bigger) one to store your new variable. You use more memory in total when concatenating with + because you have reserved memory for your string and for your concatenated string. It's just spread over 2 locations of memory instead of in 1 like with `StringBuilder`

Comment: By disabling TLBA [link](http://robsjava.blogspot.ro/2013/03/what-are-thread-local-allocation-buffers.html), I get similar resuls using both methos usedTotal: 13219192
usedTotal: 15425712

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to write this as a comment on @JRENs answer but I don't have enough rep.  The reason 2 appends take more memory is here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html

> The principal operations on a StringBuilder that are not available in String are the append() and insert() methods, which are overloaded so as to accept data of any type. Each converts its argument to a string and then appends or inserts the characters of that string to the character sequence in the string builder.

So, each append operation creates a new String, which is why 2 appends (per loop) takes roughly twice as much memory as one append.

Comment: The conversion and new string instance is just in case of  overloaded methods. If you look at append(String), it does not create a new String instance.